# HTML5/CSS - placing a large image into smaller DIV

Tags: html, css

How do we put a large image into a smaller div with h-align/v-align as centre. Image should not be visible outside of the div (kind of `overflow:hidden`). Also, div will change its size based on page size.

I took help from other question/answer and tried with div background and css - but it is aligning image to h-centre only.

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/yesprasoon/9tLcV/.

How to align both h-centre and v-centre? Also, there should not be any vertical scrollbar. It should work with any page size and (if possible) any image size. Possible with CSS only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if your are OK with resizing the image but you could go with the `background-size` property

```
.imageContainer {
  background-size:cover;
}
```

Here is my example: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7cTzL/)

**Edit**

After your comment I finally understood the problem. You can center the background-image vertically, that works, but but the vertical centering will not adapt when the height of the page changes dynamically. The reason is that your `imageContainer` div has a fixed height therefore **its own height** will not change with the *page's* height.

What you can do to remedy that is give your `imageContainer` a height of `100%`. However you will also need to have the body/html to extend to `100%` or your div will have no height in the absence of content, or be too short if you have little content.

JsFiddle doesn't deal well with body/html styles (maybe there's a trick I don't know) so I put my example on [**codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JHGzh).

**HTML**

```
<div class="imageContainer" style="background-image: url('http://www.taiwanholidays.com.au/util/image.jsp?l=791');"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0
}
.imageContainer {
  margin:0; 
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden; 
  background-position:center center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for a solution where it trims/crops the image from all four sides while retaining the image in middle. Just to add - We don't need to handle the scenario where page size is larger than image size.